# how does RSS feed application keep items marked as read? android

Tags: android, xml

I have an application that read an online xml file, now i want to implement such functionality that **when the user has clicked on item (read the item), it will marked as read**. My problem is **how to keep the old items' read status when I request again the new content from that xml file**? and when I delete the item from xml file, it then will delete such item on the phone too when the user reload the content.

Comment: Have you considered keeping a database containing the IDs of entries which have been read?

Comment: yes, i m seeking some simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to implement it:

- Keep local database (with corresponding [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)) which would store read statuses. E.g. You could have table with two fields 'Record Id in online xml' - 'Read status'. Using this way, 'read' status will bee stored locally and on another client user would see items not marked as read;
- Send server acknowledgement that the item has been read, so next request it won't be presented in the xml file (or xml file would provide it as 'read'). This way depends on the server implementation, but more convenient because 'read' status might be propagated along many clients;

Comment: In the second way, as the "read" items are not presented in the xml, so how could we still show them in the app? do we still need to use a local db to store the "read" items in the phone?

Comment: There's only one way - store them in the database. If so, You probably need to compose both ways: store items in the database (and iterate with it using Content Provider), implement logic to update 'wasRead' field while parcing xml.